# WriteableBitmap in .NET 4

Tags: .net, silverlight, bitmap, writeablebitmap

I have got a problem: I would like to use a method Render() for WriteableBitmap object. However, as I noticed, the method is not available without using a Silverlight assembly System.Windows.dll. I need to use RenderTargetBitmap in my project (PresentationCore assembly for standard .net). Here is the problem - there are definitions of some classes in both assemblies, thus they are in conflict.

Basically, I need to add some stuff to Bgra32 bitmap. However, RenderTargetBitmap works only with Pbgra32 ones. I found that using WriteableBitmap to render would be nice. Maybe I am wrong?

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you in advance for the reply!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your input to pre-multiplied alpha, do all your calculations in that color space, and convert your output back. Multiplying by alpha isn't hard to code.

Doing all calculations in pre-multiplied alpha color-space often results in better quality output(for example filtering works much better) and has some other advantages too.

[Blog-entry on the numerous advantages of using PRGBA](http://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/blog.wiki.html#%5B%5BPremultiplied%20alpha%5D%5D)

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a while ago, but it came up in a search I did for a related issue so I thought I would leave a brief answer for anyone else who stumbled upon it.

Including both the Silverlight and WPF assemblies is NOT a good idea. Pretty much everything you need from Silverlight will be in WPF in one way or another, so unless you are doing a Silverlight project (and not using WPF assemblies) don't include them!

For your problem, converting between Pbgra and Bgra is not particularly difficult and is described here:

http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/wpf-workings/538-rendertargetbitmap-visual-vector-to-bitmap.html.

Besides, RenderTargetBitmap does sort of the same thing as the Render method so you would be better off trying to use that on it's own.